# joptimizer - open source java math library tutorial or examples available?

Tags: java, joptimizer

Could someone please point me in the direction of good and detailed examples on how to use the JOptimizer library (http://www.joptimizer.com/index.html) ? The ones on their site are not very helpful. The accompanying docs are also not very detailed. Thanks!

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask)